# Xamarin Firebase - GetData failling with imported Json database

Tags: c#, database, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a bit of a severely confusing issue that I have been trying to solve for a week now and it's gotten to the point of frustration...

After much troubleshooting and trying different ways, I have concluded that the issue is coming from my **imported Firebase JSON.**

So I followed everything exactly as it is in this tutorial
**My code is exactly this:**
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/

And it works, I can add/search/load/delete etc. it shows in my Firebase database and all is dandy.
It saves it to my Firebase as this format

[image]

**HOWEVER**

when I change my firebase database, so I import my own JSON in the same format as it is being saved, like this for instance. I make sure about the String and/or Int difference.

[image]
[image]

and suddenly the same code that worked before now does not work and throws me the error because I've used my own JSON
**Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: 'Exception occurred while processing the request.**

[image]

Can someone help me before I rip my hair out :P

Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

```
I think you need to create a Model(for deserializing your response)
1-Persons.cs
public string Name {get; set;}
public int studentId {get; set;}
2-string json = @"{
  "Name":"Mark",
   "PersonID": 11,
  ]
}";
Student student= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(json);
```

Comment: Hi, im sorry im not sure I understand how to get this to work could you explain a bit further pls ? thx :)

Comment: Sure ,  First of all you need to create a model in your folder to Deserialize the Json you have from the response , In your folder create a new file with name Persons.cs , public string Name {get; set;}
public int studentId {get; set;}, Then on your app page cs when you handle api or respone just Deserialize it